# Export commits including notes

Tags: git, tfs, git-log

I want to export a change list of my release branch to a csv file, by using GIT CMD  (git version 2.19.1.windows.1).

The export should contain the *notes* containing the referenced work items. That works when I issue:

```
git log --first-parent > export.csv
```

Now I am trying to format it to display a commit per line, but I lose the *notes*:

```
git log --first-parent --format="%h;%ci;%cn;%s;%N" > export.csv
```

Why am I not seeing the *notes* with the second statement?

Comment: It seems to me that this should "just work", as long as you are running the `git log` on the same machine (notes refs are not cloned or pushed by default so if you run on a different machine, it just won't have any notes, by default).

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but it just doesn't. Maybe I can cheat by somehow transposing the results of git log to rows?

Comment: For now we have a working solution by running Excel Power Query over the export.csv. The git cmd we use now is _git log --first-parent --date=iso --format="Commit Id:%h;%ci;%cn;%s;%b" > export.csv_. I'll leave this question open so anyone can answer with a simpler solution. _%b_ stands for _body_, this field also contains the related work items.